# Need to make a list from a function

Tags: python, function, variables, math

I want to change the `a` variable from 1 to 50 and create an array from the results so that I can feed it into a curve.

The variable is outside the function but the variable changes a value in the function, that is what I need to make a list of.

```
a=1

def test(foo):
    p =a+2
    print(p)

test(foo)
```

I want to get the `p` values when I change `a` from 1 to 50:

```
[3,4,5,6,7,8,9...]
```

Comment: What is foo here? And why is it required

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you trying to do but if you need a list of numbers with some starting point, you can simply generate them using list comprehension as:

```
a = 2
x = [i+a for i in range(1, 50)]
print(x)
```

EDIT: Based on comments from author.

You need to change `print` to `return` the generated number. Also, need to add a `loop` and a `list` to generate a new number and keep `appending` the new number to the `list`.

Note: As said earlier, it is recommended to use Python's supported features like list comprehension as is shown in the original code.

```
a = 1

def test(i):
    p = a + i
    return p

res = []
for i in range(2, 50):
    res.append(test(i))

print(res)
```

Comment: So I edited it to maybe make it clearer? Did it help?

Comment: please describe how you change the `a` value when you say: `I want to get the p values when I change a from 1 to 50`

Comment: so when I change the a to 1 I get p=3, when I cange a to 2 I get p=4.

Comment: do you manually change `a`? or you want it to be done programatically?

Comment: I want it to be done automatically like with a loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227985/discussion-between-krishna-chaurasia-and-chriscross).